# Understanding jquery's animate method

Tags: jquery-animate

With the following code I can "slide" a div from right to left:

```
$("#myDiv").animate({ right: 300 }, 500);
```

While this works, I don't understand what is going on. In my html, I don't set the "right" css property, so my Div is wherever it happens to be. So what exactly is happening? Does jquery take my div and start setting the "right" attribute initially to 0 and increments it by one until it reaches a value of 300? Yet in the code sample on jquery's site, they show this:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

In this example, the "left" attribute increments in steps of 50. This is where I am confused. In my example, the "right" attribute has a fixed value and yet jquery appears to increment it in steps of one, whereas in their example it increments in steps of 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sample it is increased by 50, not the steps are 50. So if it was 200, it will be 250.

In your case it will be 300 and it is not set to 0 before it.

And yes, the inline `right` css property will be increased until it is 300.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if an attribute like "left" was never set and then you specify 50 for the animate method, jquery initially starts the value with zero and increments it by one over the animation duration until it reaches 50.

Comment: Yes, but you can see the result if you check the html element after the animation.

Answer (score 0):

In the JQuery example each time you click on #clickme the left position is moved by +50px.

In your example no matter how many times it is called it will animate once to 300px (relative to the parent div).